# How to fix jarring animation when SwiftUI moves view up for keyboard?

Tags: swiftui

I'm developing an iOS app using SwiftUI, and I'm having an issue with the animation when the view is moved up by the keyboard. Specifically, when the keyboard appears and the view is moved up, the animation looks jarring and abrupt.

I suspect this may be due to a difference in the animation curve used by the keyboard and the default animation curve used by SwiftUI. Is there a way to specify the animation curve that should be used when the view is moved up by the keyboard?

If so, how can I do this in SwiftUI? Are there any specific animation curves or durations that work well for this use case? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!